# Create a query to select data from MYSQL WHERE min(i_status) = 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I Have two MY SQL tables
OrderTable

```
+----------+--------+
| o_number | o_name |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | toys   |
|        2 | bags   |
|        3 | Laptop |
+----------+--------+
```

and itemTable

```
+----+----------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
| id | o_number | i_name | i_pcs | i_cost | i_status |
+----+----------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | item1  |     1 |      2 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 | item2  |     1 |      3 |        1 |
|  3 |        2 | item3  |     1 |      4 |        1 |
|  4 |        2 | item4  |     1 |      5 |        2 |
|  5 |        3 | item5  |     1 |      6 |        4 |
|  6 |        3 | item6  |     1 |      7 |        6 |
+----+----------+--------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Im recive all orde whit query1 -ResultTable1 - it ok

```
query1
     SELECT OrderTable *, sum(i_cost*i_pcs), min(i_status)
    LEFT JOIN ItemTable ON ItemTable.o_number = OrderTable.o_number
    GROUP BY OrderTable.o_number ORDER BY OrderTable.o_number DESC
```

ResultTable1

```
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| o_number | o_name | total_cost | min_status |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|        1 | toys   |          5 |          1 |
|        2 | bags   |          9 |          1 |
|        3 | Laptop |         13 |          4 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

but I need to receive all orders, goods with which have a minimum status of 4, and the sum of all goods from this order, not only goods with ID = 4
My query should look like this, but it does not give a result.

```
query2
 SELECT OrderTable *, sum(i_cost*i_pcs), min(i_status)
LEFT JOIN ItemTable ON ItemTable.o_number = OrderTable.o_number
WHERE min(i_status) = 4
GROUP BY OrderTable.o_number ORDER BY OrderTable.o_number DESC
```

I want to see next result:

```
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| o_number | o_name | total_cost | min_status |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|        3 | Laptop |         13 |          4 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

if I change the request where to WHERE i_status = 4  without MIN
I will get almost what I need, but the order amount will be less, since not all goods are counted.

```
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| o_number | o_name | total_cost | min_status |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|        3 | Laptop |          6 |          4 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Hello Thanks for your comment. I don’t quite understand what you mean ?, maybe I should show the table structure?

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually want here, so you should show a proper example of a set of input data, and what exact result you expect based on that. The screenshots you have shown so far aren’t that helpful, IMHO - for example what you even mean when you say “product group”, does absolutely not become clear by looking at those.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I have tried to simplify my question, please if you can give me feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking the time to resolve my issue. But I need to comply with two conditions at the same time WHERE min(i_status) = 4 AND sum(i_cost*i_pcs) whit all item status Perhaps the only answer is array processing without WHERE

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Thanks for your comment clarifying your requirements, please see my amended answer below.

The first part of your question;

> "I need to receive all orders, goods with which have a minimum status
> of 4"

is answered by changing

`WHERE min(i_status) = 4`

to

`WHERE i_status >= 4`

This will give you results where the `i_status` is "equal to OR greater than", instead of only "equal to".

If I have understood correctly, the second part of your question;

> "the sum of all goods from this order, not only goods with ID = 4"

You want the total price for **all** goods in the order. As long as at least one of those goods has a `i_status` of 4 or more.

**The following should do what you are asking.**

```
SELECT
    OrderTable.o_number,
    sum(i_cost*i_pcs),
//The following will show you the lowest item status within this order
    min(i_status)
FROM OrderTable

//Use INNER JOIN to only include orders that have items in them
INNER JOIN ItemTable
    ON ItemTable.o_number = OrderTable.o_number
WHERE 
//Use this to find orders which have goods over the minimum status
ItemTable.i_status >= 4
//Then use this to exclude orders which also include an item which is below the minimum status.
    OrderTable.o_number NOT IN
        (
            SELECT o_number
            FROM OrderTable z
            INNER JOIN ItemTable x
              ON z.o_number = x.o_number
              AND x.i_status < 4
        )
GROUP BY OrderTable.o_number
ORDER BY OrderTable.o_number DESC
```

Just add some column headings and have a good test.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to resolve my issue. But I need to comply with two conditions at the same time  WHERE min(i_status) = 4 AND sum(i_cost*i_pcs) whit all item status Perhaps the only answer is array processing without WHERE

Comment: @СергейКрюков thanks for your comment, that made it a little clearer. I have updated my answer to correct for this.